# How do I access an event's actual target when a child element triggers the event?

Tags: javascript, dom, frontend, vuejs3

I'm listening on this button for a click event, which would run `toggleSubMenu()` method of a Vue instance. I want it so that when the button is clicked I can get the `event.target`'s `parentNode` which would be the `div` with a class of `sub-menu-sibling`, and then it's `nextElementSibling` which would be the `div` with a class of `sub-menu`. This is my HTML structure.

```
<div class="sub-menu-sibling">
  <button @click.stop="toggleSubMenu($event)" class="btn" type="button" name="button">
    <svg class="bi bi-chevron-right" width="14px" height="14px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 01.708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 010 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 01-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 010-.708z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
    </svg>
    Show Menu
  </button>
</div>
<div class="sub-menu">
  <!-- menu items -->
</div>
```

This is my Vue app

```
const Menu = Vue.createApp({
  methods: {
    toggleSubMenu: function(event) {
      const subMenus = document.querySelectorAll("#categoriesMenu .sub-menu");
      let targetSubMenu = event.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling;

      targetSubMenu.classList.toggle('show');

      subMenus.forEach((sub) => {
        sub.classList.contains('show') && sub != currentSubMenu ? sub.classList.remove('show') : ''
      });
    }
  }
})
```

The problem is that when a user clicks directly on the `svg` icon inside the button, it becomes the `event.target`, which breaks my whole expectation. How do I get it to listen primarily on the button's surface alone?

Comment: I think you're looking for the `.self` modifier. See the relevant section in [the docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

===UPDATE 
I didn't know `event.currentTarget` existed.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply stop propagation on the action button

```
 const stopPropagation = event => {
    event.cancelBubble = true
    event.preventDefault()
    if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation()
  }
```

and

```
const toggleSubMenu = () => {
 stopPropagation()
 ...
}
```